# input type="file" .submit() not working IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

been driving me insane this has.  Works with everything, except... IE8 :(  File selection appears (non-images are not filtered out IE8, but that's another issue), but when you select the image the upload script is not fired, nothing gets uploaded.

The $("body").addClass("loading"); is fired (this is the loading modal), so I have no idea when the image-upload.php is not run.

Thanks folks :)

Javascript:

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'});
var fileInput = $('#file').wrap(wrapper);

$('.chooseFile').click(function(){
 fileInput.click();
}).show();

$(document).ready(function() {
 fileInput.change(function () 
  { 
   $("body").addClass("loading");
   //uploadImg.submit();
   $('#uploadImg').submit();
   this.blur();
   this.focus();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<form name="uploadImg" id="uploadImg" action="image-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btnFile">
 <div class="chooseFile">Choose File</div>
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="Select File to Upload" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Comment: How can you say `submit()` is not working? Is the `fileInput.change(function ()` function even fired?

Comment: File inputs are a pain to customize, but I went through this pain a while ago. In IE you need to trigger the dialog on the label, it's the only workaround that seems to work. Check this plugin. You can just copy paste into your project and call `$('#file').idealFile()`. Then customize it with CSS. https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms/blob/master/js/src/file.js

Comment: Yes, fileInput.change(function () is fired as the loading modal is fired. Thanks

Comment: OMG OMG! elclanrs thankyou!!  I've been on this for three days!  Finally working, suck on that IE8!  Thanks so much mate, made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'});
var fileInput = $('#file').wrap(wrapper);
$('.chooseFile').click(function(){
 fileInput.click();
}).show();
```

inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Just tried that, no difference :(  Thanks for the suggestion though :)